# PHP exec() unable to fork base64 string?

Tags: php

I'm using the exec() function in PHP to run a JavaScript file through CLI.
The JavaScript simply uses process.argv[n] to acquire the arguments passed in from the exec().

Everything works as expected while passing the other arguments, however, I would like to pass a base64 string as an argument. The string is quite large and breaks the exec() function with a warning letting me know that the function was unable to fork.

Could this possibly have something to do with a memory limitation? I'm unsure how to address this issue.

here is the entire PHP portion of the program in question:

```
<?php
$path = './exampleDir/example.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
$base64 = "data:image/".$type.";base64,".$data;

$cfPage = "index";
$iwidth = "400";
$iheight = "425";
$iaspect = $iwidth/$iheight;

exec("node ./scripts/test.js ".$cfPage." ".uniqid()." ".$iaspect." ".$base64);
?>
```

I've tried passing simple strings of lengths less than 100 characters into the exec() which pass in just fine. I believe the length of the string is the issue, and perhaps this is something to do with memory limitations?

Comment: make a temp .sh file instead then run that, though is also not ideal to put an image into a .sh script, why not change it so the js file loads the image, its trival with [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: How big is the Base64 string you're having trouble with?

Comment: This is currently in testing, so I'm just working out some mechanics right now, but the plan is for a user to input an image file through a form, then encode it to base64 for some mission critical functions down the line. I reflexively thought to encode the file within PHP, but certainly I could just encode the file in the JavaScript! That's a very good point!

So instead I'll just pass the location of the temporary file from the form as an argument to the exec().

Comment: The string is something around 483,246 characters in length.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit

Comment: ah @shingo that does clarify things, thank you!